# How to properly benchmark latency over LAN?

Tags: networking, performance, ping

I'm trying to estimate latency over LAN. To do so obvious idea was to use `ping`. So here it goes:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.241 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.190 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.177 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.190 ms
```

Okay well but there's a firewall so maybe 1 second is interrupting conntrack in firewall, lets try smaller interval `ping -i 0.05`:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=27 ttl=64 time=0.119 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=28 ttl=64 time=0.106 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=29 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=30 ttl=64 time=0.109 ms
```

It looks signigicantly faster. So lets take even smaller interval `ping -i 0.005`:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2139 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2140 ttl=64 time=0.073 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2141 ttl=64 time=0.056 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2142 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
```

At this point I collected big log of pings, then calculated average and it turned out to be: `0.068 ms`. When I repeated test for 8k jumbo frames `ping -M do -s 8000`. it settled around 0.220 ms.

So the question is - what is actual latency? Why decreasing interval decreases ping response time as well?

I'm more interested in big-throughput latency than occasional one because it's supposed to route NFSv4, so probably 0.220 is realistic one but I'd like someone to confirm.

Comment: Describe your LAN between the device and its ping target. Is the device on Wi-Fi? Are there any Wi-Fi or other non-802.3 links in the path? Variable ping times on Wi-Fi are common due to power saving algorithms that turn off the radio between bursts. Lowering inter-ping latency can cause the radios to not turn off as often, which lowers round-trip latency. Sending packets very close together can allow frame aggregation to happen, further lowering latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a better tool than ping, look at the open source Flent tool. [Flent](https://flent.org/), the "FLExible Network Tester", is a throughput-with-latency test tool created by some very smart networking researchers who spent many years looking at how network latency degrades under load (particularly the [bufferbloat](https://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/) problem).

Most people measuring latency on their network don't really care as much about latency between small once-per-second packets on an otherwise idle network, they care more about the latency involved in a large packet flow. That's what Flent tests.